# What is the most efficient way to find the inverse of large matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a large square $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ invertible matrix, where $n \approx 1000$.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & a_0\\
1 & -1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & a_1\\
0 & 1 & -1 &\cdots & 0 & a_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & -1 & a_{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 1 & a_n-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

What is the most efficient way to find its inverse or solve its linear equation?

Matrix $A$ is the result of a subtraction of a matrix with the identity matrix. I try to solve this to find the result of the series of a matrix and apparently Gaussian elimination method was not efficient enough.

Comment: Have you tried using LU factorisation? It may be a problem solvable using LU factorisation and induction.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso i haven't tried that yet, do you have any detailed explanation or references for that you can kindly share? Thanks!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, $A  = C - I$, where $C$ is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Correct?

Comment: How fast are you hoping it will be?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm not really sure, but it's almost identical so it must be it

Comment: @littleO definitely faster than Gaussian elimination method, ideally around $O(n^2)$

Comment: If you figured out how to do it in $O(n^2)$, that'd be a huge development.  IIRC the current fastest method is around $O(n^{2.3})$. Also cs.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask, but this question has been asked there many times before.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I'm not sure what you mean by "sleepy".  [cs.SE is significantly more active than scicomp.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft What makes this question interesting is the particular structure that OP's matrix has, which makes it possible to solve $Ax = b$ in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Apparently, the **correct** answer to this question is "Ask Math.SE."  Perhaps ask about "computational complexity" to avoid this meta-answer...

Comment: You may get some tips by looking at the old Linpack 1000 and related benchmarks. When I was doing performance measurement on some servers, 1000x1000 was too small to be a good test and we used much larger matrices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's solve $Ax = b$. The first equation in this linear system tells us that
$-x_0 + a_0 x_n = b_0$, or 
$$
x_0 = a_0 x_n - b_0.
$$
The second equation tells us that
\begin{align}
& x_0 - x_1 + a_1 x_n = b_1 \\
\implies & x_1 = (a_0 + a_1) x_n - b_0 -  b_1.
\end{align}
The third equation tells us that
\begin{align}
&x_1 - x_2 + a_2 x_n = b_2 \\
\implies & x_2 = (a_0 + a_1 + a_2) x_n - b_0 - b_1 - b_2.
\end{align}
Continuing like this, the second-to-last equation tells us that
\begin{align}
& x_{n-1} = (a_0 + \cdots + a_{n-1}) x_n - b_0 - \cdots - b_{n-1}.
\end{align}
The final equation tells us that
\begin{align}
&x_{n-1} + (a_n - 1) x_n = b_n \\
\implies& (a_0 + \cdots + a_{n-1}) x_n - b_0 - \cdots - b_{n-1} + (a_n - 1) x_n = b_n \\
\implies & (-1 + \sum_{i=0}^n a_i)x_n - \sum_{i=0}^n b_i = 0 \\
\implies & x_n = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n b_i }{-1 + \sum_{i=0}^n a_i}.
\end{align}
We can now do back-substitution to get the values of $x_{n-1}, \ldots, x_0$.

So we can solve $Ax = b$ in linear time.

Answer (score 8):

Gaussian Elimination should be plenty fast, so perhaps the issue is how you are implementing it. We want to solve

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & a_0\\
1 & -1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & a_1\\
0 & 1 & -1 &\cdots & 0 & a_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & -1 & a_{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 1 & a_n-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_{n-1} \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_{n-1} \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$$

By applying $R_{i+1} \leftarrow R_{i+1} + R_i$ for $i=0, 1, \ \ldots \ , n-1$ we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \alpha_0\\
0 & -1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \alpha_1\\
0 & 0 & -1 &\cdots & 0 & \alpha_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & -1 & \alpha_{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \alpha_n-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_{n-1} \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}\beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_{n-1} \\ \beta_n\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\alpha_k = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i$ and $\beta_k = \sum_{i=0}^k b_i.$ Make sure to compute the $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ recursively so that you only use $2n$ additions (instead of computing each naively, which would use about $n^2$ additions).

Now we do back substitution. First we have $x_n = \beta_n (\alpha_n-1)^{-1}$ which costs $1$ division. Then for $i=0, 1, 2, \ \ldots, n-1$ we have $x_i = \alpha_i x_n - \beta_i,$ which takes $n$ multiplications and $n$ subtractions to compute.

Answer (score 6):

$$\mathrm{A} = \left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right) + \mathrm{a} \mathrm{e}_{n+1}^\top$$

where $\rm{S}$ is a (nilpotent) lower [shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix). Using [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula),

$$\mathrm{A}^{-1} = \left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)^{-1} - \frac{\left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)^{-1} \mathrm{a} \mathrm{e}_{n+1}^\top\left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)^{-1}}{1 + \mathrm{e}_{n+1}^\top \left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)^{-1} \mathrm{a}}$$

where, using the [nilpotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) of $\rm{S}$,

$$\left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)^{-1} = - \left( \mathrm{I}_{n+1} + \mathrm{S} + \mathrm{S}^2 + \cdots + \mathrm{S}^n \right) = - \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}}_{=: \rm{L}}$$

and, hence,

$$1 + \mathrm{e}_{n+1}^\top \left( \mathrm{S} - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)^{-1} \mathrm{a} = 1 - \mathrm{e}_{n+1}^\top \mathrm{L} \, \mathrm{a} = 1 - \Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top \mathrm{a}$$

and, thus,

$$\mathrm{A}^{-1} = - \mathrm{L} - \frac{\mathrm{L} \, \mathrm{a} \Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top}{1 - \Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top \mathrm{a}} = \left(\frac{1}{\Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top \mathrm{a} - 1}\right) \mathrm{L} \, \mathrm{a} \Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top - \mathrm{L} = \color{blue}{\mathrm{L} \left( \left(\frac{1}{\Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top \mathrm{a} - 1}\right) \, \mathrm{a} \Bbb{1}_{n+1}^\top - \mathrm{I}_{n+1} \right)}$$

which seems to agree with Daniel's answer.